# Java Singleton has different toString() value

Tags: java, singleton

I have a classic singleton implemented in java

```
public class ClassicSingleton {

   private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;

   private ClassicSingleton() {} ;

   public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            return new ClassicSingleton();
        return instance;
   }
}
```

I have the following driver

```
public class SingletonDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ClassicSingleton.getInstance().toString());
        System.out.println(ClassicSingleton.getInstance().toString());
    }
}
```

The output is something like

```
ClassicSingleton@75e4f66a
ClassicSingleton@aede59e
```

I thought the output would be pointing to the same object.  Shouldn't the values be the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your implementation of `getInstance()` is wrong. You never initialize `instance`, and thus return a new instance on each invocation. If `instance` is `null`, you should save it to your data member, and only then return it:

```
public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new ClassicSingleton();
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: This isn't thread safe. You need DCL with volatile, an inner class holder, or a non-lazy assignment to the static variable.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to assign `new ClassicSingleton()` to `instance`, so you actually have a factory instead of a singleton; you'll create a new instance on every call. (Note also, of course, that this isn't thread-safe.)